# apache https the connection was restarted

Tags: apache-2.2, https

im getting this error after 1 minute trying to load in all web browsers, i created a virtualhost my_ip:443 in ssl.conf with a self signed certificate but the browser never load it.

i will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in IPTABLES, the `https` (443) port was badly configured.